# How to control nested scrollviews

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

In my iphone application I want to use 2 scrollviews and they have some images inside. Well, my question is when I scroll vertically on my first scrollview I want to explore the content of it however when I scroll horizontally I want to move to my second scrollview. I hope I explained clearly.

Well, I tried to use 3 scrollviews first of them located on the background, others are located on the first scrollview but I can only control the background scrollview or the others at once.

Is there a way to control first one horizontally and the others vertically.sorry for my english, hope it makes sense.

Comment: Nested scroll views is generally not encouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two recommendations.

1)  Scrollviews can scroll horizontally and vertically - so you dont need two of them if you have content in a vertical direction and content in a horizontal direction.  You can use one.

2) If for some reason you really do need 2, then you can detect a horizontal swipe by subclassing `UIScrollView` and switch to the other.

Remember that a `UIScrollView` will scroll in any direction that exceeds its contentSize.  So all you need to do in the first case (1) is take the view that is inside say scrollview 2 (the horizontal scrollview) and put that view in the scroll view to the left or the right outside of the scrollviews viewport when the user scrolls they will see that view and can of course scroll vertically there as well.

If you use method 2 - make sure that the content size of scrollview one is at leat a few pixels more wide than the content size so that you can detect a horizontal swipe then invoke the coe to switch to your other scroll view.  If you dont subclass `UIScrollview` to get the swipe you probably wont get the event. So do that add a little to the width of that view and then look for a value less than the left edge of the scroll view and switch to the other scroll view.  You can do the same in reverse to go back to the previous scrollview.

I hope this helps - sorry no code at the moment, but I do have code working on iOS and OSX that does this.

Answer (score 1):

You can distinguish both `UIScrollView` via `if statement` 
Set delegate of both `UIScrollView`
Then compare your `scrollView` in its `delegate` method. You can change your `delegate` method according to your requirement -

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate 
{
    if(firstScrollView == scrollView)
    {
         //Do your work for firstScrollView
    }

    if(secondScrollView == scrollView)
    {
         //Do your work for secondScrollView
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do in delegates methords

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

set some conditions like

```
if(myScroll1)
{
 //scroll vatical.
}
if(myScroll2)
{
 //scroll horizontal.
}
```

this is not complete code this is an idea Best of luck..

Comment: I tried but I dont think it is what I am looking for. thanks anyway:)